# Angular JS: GridOptions.filterOptions not working

Tags: angularjs

Can any one please tell me how to use **gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText** I have a grid with a column header that has a drop down. which looks like this

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle grad1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <b>Impact</b><span class="caret"></span></button>    
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="position:fixed;top:inherit;left:320px;">
    <li><a ng-click="$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='Impact:H'">Higher</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='Impact:M'">Medium(M)</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='Impact:L'">Low(L)</a></li>
```

I have tried removing **$scope** and using **$parent** and also tried combinations but didn't get any results.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I found the answer.
There is a work around for this as follows

**in HTML**
Replace the **LI tags** with this

```
<li><a ng-click="filterImpact('')">All</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="filterImpact('H')">High</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="filterImpact('M')">Medium</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="filterImpact('L')">Low</a></li>
```

**in Controllers**
add function

```
    $scope.filterImpact = function(x) {
    if (x=='') {
        $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='';
        return;
    }
    $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='Impact:'+x;
  }
```

and in ColumnDefs write this

```
     filterOptions: {filterText: '', useExternalFilter: false},
```

Please write the above line. It is very important otherwise the filter won't work.

Is there a  better solution that can filter the grid in HTML page without writing any functions in controllers?

Comment: what is `$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText`? in templates you do not use `$scope` part in identifiers.

Comment: Yes I was using $parent in html but didn't gave me good results..

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work:

```
<li><a ng-click="gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText=''">All</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='Impact:H'">High</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='Impact:M'">Medium</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText='Impact:L'">Low</a></li>
```

Comment: @aksonsu Nope I did try that.. that doesn't work because the gridOption is not available in HTML file. :(

Comment: maybe you can set up a plnkr.co page that reproduces the problem?